# NSNotification EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: xcode, exc-bad-access, nsnotificationcenter

Here is the error I am getting

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xb7ffffc)
```

On this line

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AsyncImageLoadDidFinish
                                                        object:target
                                                      userInfo:[[userInfo copy] autorelease]];
```

In the AsyncImageView.m file.

The error stops the code but if I continue in debugger it freezes Xcode and shuts it down. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: How did you declare `userInfo`?

Comment: `  NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           image, AsyncImageImageKey,
           URL, AsyncImageURLKey,
           nil];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below, it should be okay:

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:..., nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AsyncImageLoadDidFinish
                                                    object:target
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
```

or:

```
NSDictionary * userInfo = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:..., nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AsyncImageLoadDidFinish
                                                    object:target
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
[userInfo release];
```

Comment: That works but I also got a new AsyncImagView.m and the line became this `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AsyncImageLoadDidFinish
               object:_target
                userInfo:[[userInfo copy] autorelease]];`

Comment: @BigT Sorry, I'm not very clear about what you said..Have you solved the issue??

Comment: Yes I have. That line worked but I updated the AsyncImageView.m and that line was there instead. Both work.

Answer (score 15):

In init you need to register, and in dealloc you need to un register!

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AsyncImageLoadDidFinish  object:nil];
```

OR

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```